# Make Kibana 4 remain running after disconnecting SSH session

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I've installed ElasticSearch and Kibana edge versions on a Ubuntu Linux 14 box. So that's Kibana 4 on ElasticSearch 1.4.4.

Runs and works like a charm through: `./bin/kibana`

However, as soon as I disconnect my Putty session, Kibana stops working. ElasticSearch keeps listening on port 9200, but Kibana cannot be reached at 5601 anymore.

Difference seems to be that Kibana runs in the 'foreground' - since as soon as you run it - you see log messages flying by all the time. Using `-q` will make it quiet indeed - but not run in the background.

So I read somewhere that running it in the background might work: `./bin/kibana &`. It doesn't. Neither does `CTRL-Z and then bg` work.

So maybe, the reason is that I run Kibana under the logged in user and when I log out, it kills all processes of that user. So I tried `sudo adduser kibanarunner` and `sudo -u kibanarunner ./bin/kibana` but that didn't do the trick either.

I want Kibana to stay up-and-running after I stop my SSH session - how can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can detach the process from your session.

```
./bin/kibana &
disown
```

Comment: Seems to work! Awesome. let me verify this and then I'll mark as answered.

Answer (score 7):

The answer from Louis-Philippe Huberdeau wasn't working for me, so this is my solution:

```
sh kibana-4.0.1-linux-x64/bin/kibana >> /var/log/kibana.log(or /dev/null) &
```

Comment: thank you Johny Host, your answer is working for me too and i think this one should be marked as correct answer

Answer (score 4):

I find running Kibana4 as a service the most convenient practice. It works (near flawlessly) even after you disconnect SSH. One can (re)start/stop it with one simple command. To run Kibana as a service, first download the kibana4 init script:

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thisismitch/8b15ac909aed214ad04a/raw/bce61d85643c2dcdfbc2728c55a41dab444dca20/kibana4
```

Enable the Kibana4 service and you're good to go:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/kibana4
sudo update-rc.d kibana4 defaults 96 9
sudo service kibana4 start
```

Complete credits to this answer goes to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-ubuntu-14-04) wonderful step-by-step ELK installation guide. You can do likewise for Elasticsearch, Logstash and Logstash-forwarder as well.

Comment: Sigh.  Would it kill Elastic to document some of these things?  Their install instructions for Kibana are pretty weak.  The only init.d scripts I've had to write myself in the last 2 years are tied to their products.

Answer (score 3):

You should try using

> screen -d -m ./bin/kibana

Or another useful way:

> nohup ./bin/kibana > kibana.log 2>&1 &

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this command (ubuntu):
`nohup ./kibana/bin/kibana &`